# OpenSSL ECDSA sign and verify file

Tags: cryptography, openssl, digital-signature, ecdsa

I would like to sign and verify a pdf with elliptic curve. I got some code but it doesn't work.

Create private key:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 -noout -out private.pem
```

Create public key:

```
openssl ec -in private.pem -pubout -out public.pem
```

Sign file:

```
openssl dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 test.pdf > hash openssl dgst
openssl dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -inkey private.pem -keyform PEM -in hash > signature
```

Verify file:

```
openssl dgst -ecdsa-with-SHA1 -verify public.pem -signature signature.bin data
```

The part to sign and verify doesn't work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was asked/answered on SuperUser - http://superuser.com/questions/737574/openssl-ecdsa-sign-and-verify-file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting these command line options from - the help for `dgst` doesn't indicate that `-ecdsa-with-SHA1`, `-inkey` or `-in` are valid options. Try:

Sign:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -sign private.pem < test.pdf > signature.bin
```

Verify:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify public.pem -signature signature.bin < test.pdf
```